# delete more than one id from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to delete rows with duplicate values for "**driverid**"?. 
I want to remove all duplicated entries if any for each record.
Please see below image, I want query how do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EXISTS()

```
DELETE FROM YourTable p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable pp
             WHERE p.DriverID = pp.DriverID
               AND p.id > pp.id)
```